# Chrome does not properly implement getElementsByClassName: cannot use multiple classes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, webkit

The specs for `getElementsByClassName` state that you can search for multiple classes at once by putting them in a space-separated-string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

```
/* From MDN */
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names); // or:
elements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

- elements is a HTMLCollection of found elements.
- **names is a string representing the list of class names to match; class names are separated by whitespace**
- getElementsByClassName can be called on any element, not only on the document. The element on which it is called will be used as the root of the search.

But trying this on Chrome gives zero results! Has anyone been able to get this to work in Chrome? Is it just Chrome or WebKit?

Comment: It [works](http://jsbin.com/isusir/1/edit) in my copy of Chrome.

Comment: @Quentin That's not how it it's supposed to work. It should be able to pick up these two divs, but it returns zero: http://jsbin.com/isusir/2/edit

Comment: @DonRhummy actually that is exactly how it is supposed to work "Returns a set of elements which have ALL the given class names"

Comment: Same here, works just like it says on the box. I'll also note, the order of the classes passed to getElementsByClassName didn't matter for elements with 2 classes(didn't try others). I.e `"class1 class2"` returned the same number of results as `"class2 class1"`. Test environment: Chrome version 28.0.1500.52 m, Win7, 64bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss understood it is NOT an OR. It is an AND.

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("foo bar");
```

It says the element needs to have both class `foo` and `bar`.

```
<div class="foo">Not Selected</div>
<div class="bar">Not Selected</div>
<div class="foo bar">Selected</div>
```

The variable elements will only find the last element in that set above.

[Running Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTXtR/)

If you want to do an or, you can use [`quersySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) on modern day browsers

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".foo, .bar");
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wmcUP/)

Comment: I updated my answer to show you a way how to do an or with `querySelectorAll`. Hopefully that gets what you were after.